# How did Weibull derive the three parameter Weibull distribution?

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, statistics

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAuui.png]

How did Weibull or any other mathematician arrive at the above expression? I saw the 1951 paper, but it is not clear to me. In 1939 he had published a book called "A Statistical Theory of the Strength of Materials", and I am currently searching for this book. In the meantime can anyone explain me.

Comment: Not a book so much as a journal article:  W. WEIBULL, "A statistical theory of the strength of materials," Ing. Vetenskaps Akad … 293-297.  appearing in a Swedish engineering journal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0266892094900043) "Strength of materials and the Weibull distribution" by  Eric S. Lindquist in *Probabilistic Engineering Mechanics* **9** (1994) 191-194 probably has what you want.
I found several online copies with a "weibull's original paper" google search, but they might be behind institutional paywalls.

Weibull's 1939  paper "A statistical theory of the strength of materials" seems to have appeared in what [WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/title/ingeniorsvetenskapsakademiens-handlingar-proceedings-royal-swedish-academy-of-engineering-sciences-the-royal-swedish-institute-for-scientific-engineering-research-formerly-proceedings-the-royal-swedish-institute-for-engineering-research/oclc/888476918?referer=di&ht=edition) says was this journal:

> Ingeniörsvetenskapsakademiens handlingar = Proceedings / Royal Swedish Academy of engineering sciences the Royal Swedish Institute for scientific engineering research = formerly: Proceedings / the Royal Swedish Institute for engineering research

in volume 151, pp.1-45.  I have not found any on-line copies of this paper.
WorldCat lists libraries on 3 continents with this journal; the nearset to me is about 100 km away from where I live, the 6-th nearest in another country.

Two of the 3 parameters, $\gamma$ and $\eta$ (this is me talking, not Lindquist) are location and scale parameters, more or less inevitable in any technological application. The third, $\beta$ is the interesting one.